# subscribe loads data after execution of code in angular 2

Tags: angular

I'm creating an angular 2 app in which I had implemented multi language translation. So What i need to do is change language based on user preference.

Here are the codes..

```
public trans: any;
public instant(){
var str = "Hello";
this.setLanguage("hi-IN");
return this.translate(str);
}

public setLanguage(lang: string){
this.http.get('url').subscribe((data) => {
this.trans = data;
}
}

public translate(key: string){
if(this.trans[key]){ var translated = this.trans[key];
  return translated;
 }
}
```

What the case here is if I make an http call in constructor and fill the trans object then the translation happens. but if I call it on demand then translate() is excuted first and then setLanguage(), so it fails.

Comment: Can you share more code on this matter. Constructor etc

Answer (score 0):

You can use promise instead of subscribe see the below code.

```
public setLanguage(lang: string){
   var data= this.http.get('url').map(res => res.json()).toPromise();
   promise.then(data =>this.trans = data);
   return promise
}
```